# Error: No event 'socketConnect' in state 'SentPrelogin'

Tags: node.js, sql-server, database, knex.js

I am trying to connect my SQL Server database with node.js using knex but I am facing issue

```
Error: No event 'socketConnect' in state 'SentPrelogin'
    at Connection.dispatchEvent (C:\Users\temp\Documents\PRactice\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1281:26)
    at Connection.socketConnect (C:\Users\temp\Documents\PRactice\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1303:10)
    at C:\Users\temp\Documents\PRactice\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1145:12
    at Socket.onConnect (C:\Users\temp\Documents\PRactice\node_modules\tedious\lib\connector.js:106:7)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:314:20)
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1131:10)
Emitted 'error' event on Connection instance at:
    at Connection.dispatchEvent (C:\Users\temp\Documents\PRactice\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1281:12)
    at Connection.socketConnect (C:\Users\temp\Documents\PRactice\node_modules\tedious\lib\connection.js:1303:10)
    [... lines matching original stack trace ...]
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:1131:10)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

My code is

```
var knex = require('knex')({  
  client: 'mssql',
  version:"7_1",  
   connection: {  
    user: 'sa',  
    password: 'Admin@123',  
    server: 'localhost',  
    database: 'Demo'  
   }  
 });  

 knex.select("*").from("Country")  
 .then(function (depts){  
   depts.forEach((dept)=>{ //use of Arrow Function  
     console.log({...dept});  
   });  
 }).catch(function(err) {  
 // All the error can be checked in this piece of code  
   console.log(err);  
 }).finally(function() {  
   // To close the connection pool  
   knex.destroy();  
 });
```

Comment: `version:"7_1"`? Are you trying to connect to SQL Server 2000? Modern SQL Servers should be using the default TDS Version, 7.4.

Comment: I am using SQL server 2019

Answer (score 7):

You need to add a missing dependency:

```
npm install --save tedious
```

As of knex v0.95.0 you'll need to use the `tedious` library instead of `mssql` when connecting to an MSSQL database. According to the [knex upgrade instructions](https://github.com/knex/knex/blob/master/UPGRADING.md#upgrading-to-version-0950):

> MSSQL driver was completely reworked in order to address the multitude of connection pool, error handling and performance issues. Since the new implementation uses `tedious` library directly instead of `mssql`, please replace `mssql` with `tedious` in your dependencies if you are using a MSSQL database.

Installing the package above should resolve your issue. I also had to set the `encrypt` option to `false` when connecting to my local database to avoid this error:

```
ConnectionError: Failed to connect to localhost:1433 - self signed certificate
```

Comment: Thanks, it works. The main problem is that Knex documentation continues to say that `npm install mssql`